# How to docker attach to a container - Google Cloud Platform / Kubernetes

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a containerized app running on a VM.  It consists of two docker containers. The first contains the WebSphere Liberty server and the web app. The second contains PostgreSQL and the app's DB.

On my local VM, I just use ***docker run*** to start the two containers and then I use ***docker attach*** to attach to the web server container so I can edit the server.xml file to specify the public host IP for the DB and then start the web server in the container.  The app runs fine.

Now I'm trying to deploy the app on Google Cloud Platform.

1. I set up my gcloud configuration (project, compute/zone).
2. I created a cluster.
3. I created a JSON pod config file which specifies both containers.
4. I created the pod.
5. I opened the firewall for the port specified in the pod config file.

At this point:

1. I look at the pod (***gcloud preview container kubectl get pods***), it
   shows both containers are running.
2. I SSH to the cluster (***gcloud compute ssh xxx-mycluster-node-1***) and issue ***sudo docker ps*** and it shows the database container running, but not the web server container.  With ***sudo docker ps -l*** I can see the web server container that is not running, but it keeps trying to start and exiting every 10 seconds or so.

So now I need to  update the server.xml and start the Liberty server, but I have no idea how to do that in this realm.  Can I attach to the web server container like I do in my local VM?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like the web server container is crash looping. Have you looked at its logs to see what the error is? You can do this remotely using 'gcloud preview container kubectl log <pod-id> <container-id>'.

Comment: When I check the log for the running DB container, I get the log msgs that I expect, but when I try to check the log for the web server container, I just get "Internal Error: container "mycontainer" is not ready." which is not helpful.   That issue was previously mentioned here:  https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/issues/4526

Comment: @RobertBailey is it possible to look at the logs for the last (or any previous ) instance of the crash looping container?   Once a container is running, is it possible to attach to it?

Comment: I'm not sure, as I've never personally encountered this problem. One thought is to look at /var/log/kubelet.log and see if it has anything interesting.

Comment: Why does the database need the public host IP? If you are running the two containers in a single pod in Kubernetes they should share the loopback address and you should be able to connect them on 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Also try 'gcloud preview container kubectl describe <pod>' and 'gcloud preview container kubectl get events' to see if they print anything that would point to the cause of the crash loop.

Answer (score 21):

Yes, you can attach to a container in a pod.
Using Kubernetes 1.0 issue the following command:

Do:

- `kubectl get po` to get the POD name
- `kubectl describe po POD-NAME` to find container name

Then:

`kubectl exec -it POD-NAME -c CONTAINER-NAME bash` Assuming you have bash

Its similar to `docker exec -it CONTAINER-NAME WHAT_EVER_LOCAL_COMMAND`

Answer (score 0):

On the machine itself, you can see crash looping containers via:

docker ps -a

and then

docker logs

you can also use kubectl get pods  -oyaml to get details like restart count that will validate that the container is crash-looping.

Comment: good to note this one too to debug things `kubectl logs {pod_id}`